# How to copy one model pose to another?

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature

I would like to change the position of the bottom model to look like the one on the top.

Is there anyway to do this automatically? Without manually adjusting the bones? They are completely different models from different sources.

[image: Top Model]

[image: Bottom Model]

Comment: Hello, is the armature the same (same bones with same names)? If not I don't think that there's any trick, you need to pose it manually

Comment: hey, yeah they are not the same bones neither the same names.  So posing is my only option for this task?

Comment: I guess so but there may an option that I don't know

Comment: will see other replies! thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: Is the bottom skeleton in default pose? If not, selecting all the bones in pose mode and hitting alt+R and alt+G will reset the pose. This might look more like the default T pose on the top model.
You could also rename the bones so they have the same names as the bottom model and copy-paste the pose. Even  if it's not the same bones presumably the skeletons have a similar structure on the hands and arms

Comment: yeah the bottom is also in default pose its just the arms and hands bent like that. I could try that but the number of bones is also significantly more.  I have to align that model cause im trying to do a character replacement mod for a game lol.